# Is there a way to stop MYSQL Delayed Inserts from the MySQL configuration?

Tags: mysql, delayed-execution

I got stuck with a weird issue with one of our servers. I see there are delayed mysql inserts

```
+--------+----------------+-----------+------------------+----------------+------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id     | User           | Host      | db               | Command        | Time | State              | Info                                                                                                 |
+--------+----------------+-----------+------------------+----------------+------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 219586 | DELAYED        | localhost | XXXX             | Delayed insert | 202  | Waiting for INSERT |                                                                                                      |
```

on a rarely used databases. From what I understood from the MySQL manual, those inserts wait for other ones in order to optimize highly used databases to write inserts in batches/blocks. Unfortunately they say that this method consumes a lot of memory and is extremely inefficient when used on rarely utilized databases. In this particular case there are only 10-20 queries a day to that database which makes the delays extremely huge -- up to a whole day. There are similar issues with other databases/users and when added up they seem to load MySQL's memory usage and CPU.

Is there a way to prevent delayed queries from being delayed ? Like make em act like regular queries ?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Venetsian.

Answer (score 5):

1. You may FLUSH TABLES or 'KILL 219586' to force that thread complete its job and exit
2. Set `max_delayed_threads=0` in config file and restart instance to disable DELAYED feature completely
3. Read docs - it will be faster than waiting 6h in forum

Comment: @noonex - 6h waiting for an answer is generally less painful than trying to decipher the MySql documentation, particularly if you're running MySql on windows as differences are subtle enough to cause headaches =)

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about that thread. It's just kept around in case there's a delayed insert in the future. It's not actually doing anything..